# Removing items from a dynamically added List<Widget> on Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am struggling with removing items from the list generated. I am fairly new to flutter and programming. Can someone help? I have read through a few articles and I couldn't understand any of them.

```dart
class AddPoll extends StatefulWidget {
      AddPoll({
        Key key,
        this.items,
        this.index,
      }): super(key: key);
      final Map items;
      final int index;
      @override
      AddPollState createState() => new AddPollState();
    }


    class AddPollState extends State < AddPoll > {

      int _index = 0;
      String q;
      Map formData = {};

      Map answers = {};
      var _items = List < Widget > ();

      _remove(keyValue) {

        print(keyValue);
        // List.from(_items)..removeAt(keyValue);
        answers.remove(keyValue);
        // answers.
      }

      void _add() {
        int keyValue = _index;
        _items = List.from(_items)..add(
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Answer ${keyValue+1}',
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(icon: Icon(Feather.minus_circle), onPressed: () {
                    _remove(keyValue);
                  })
                ),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  answers["a$keyValue"] = val;
                },

              ),
          ),
        );
        setState(() => ++_index);
      }

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _add();
      }

      save() async {

        formData = {

          'q': q,
          'a': answers
        };
        print(formData);
        Navigator.pop(context, formData);
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {


        return Scaffold(

          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: Text("Add Question"),
            actions: < Widget > [
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Save"),
                textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                onPressed: () {
                  save();
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
          body: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: < Widget > [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Question ${widget.index + 1}'

                    ),
                    onChanged: (val) => q = val,
                  ),
              ),

              ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: _items,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
                  child: FlatButton(onPressed: _add, child: Text("Add another answer"), 

              )

            ],
          ),

        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: so what errors are you getting?

Comment: I wasn't getting any errors. but the answer below solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: Hello @bigmints I have a similar widgwet, with your code I could notice a bug, I don't know if you have solved it, I'll explain: If you add 3 answers with the text "one", "two" and "three" respectively and you remove answer 2, answer two is removed but it remains three in TextField. Let me know if this issue happened to you and how you solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your remove method should be like below,

```
  _remove(keyValue) {
    setState(() {

      _items = List.from(_items)..removeAt(keyValue);
      --keyValue;
      --_index;      
    });
  }
```